# Not able to change output timestamp variable in proper oracle standard format

Tags: python, python-3.x, oracle

```py
cur.execute("select max(insertdate) from iipmdbse.I_SalesOrder")
data = cur.fetchone()
print(data)
```

Output :

`(datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 17, 10, 1, 22, 634000),)`

But I want output in this format `17-DEC-19 10.01.22.634000000 AM`.

Answer (score 2):

First, fetchone() returns a tuple of column values so we'll need to unpack that tuple to get the insertdate.
Next, we use [datetime.strftime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime) to format the date to your liking.

```py
cur.execute("select max(insertdate) from iipmdbse.I_SalesOrder")
data = cur.fetchone()
insertdate, = data
print(insertdate.strftime('%d-%b-%y %I:%M:%S.%f %p').upper())
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use to_char function to format the datetime into a character string.
Check the Oracle Document for [to_char](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm)

Comment: It is much smarter to retrieve a `DATE` value from database and make the formatting at client side, i.e. in python.